# How can I add a "group member" field to my Organic Group content type?

Tags: users, entities, organic-groups

I want to create a content type called “task” that includes a field that is a select list of all members in the group.  The person creating the content should be able to select the group member that the task is “assigned to”.

When I try to create this using an entity reference field, I select “target type = user” and “mode = simple (with optional filter by bundle)”.  The field doesn’t show up when creating content here.  Instead the error message is displayed: Field Assigned to is a group-audience but its Entity selection mode is not defined as "Organic groups" in the field settings page.

However, when I change try to change the field’s entity selection mode, I get the following error message: Error: The selected "Target type" User does not have bundles that are a group type.

So is it impossible to add a multi-select field that is a list of group members to a group content type?